# Trying to show a GridView next to a Listview. GridView does not display

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, gridview

I want a vertical ListView on the left and a GridView to the right of it.  Both are backed by ArrayAdapters.  I have tried RelativeLayout and LinearLayout, and the GridView does not even call the Adapter (Unless stacked vertically).  I put a Log.v in the adapter with the parent ID to prove it.  With a TableLayout the Grid's Adapter does set the fields, but the Grid is still not visible.  The two Views do show the same TextView item within them.  The rest of the fragment displays fine.  The ListView always displays.

The XML Using the TableLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_course"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.hubbardsoftware.racetac.CourseActivityFragment"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_course">

<fragment android:name="com.hubbardsoftware.racetac.TimerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_timer" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/course"/>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TableRow>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_course"
        android:layout_column="1"
        />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview_course"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="none" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And the Fragment code:

```
        // Setup the List of Marks in the course.
    ArrayList<Mark> course = appData.getCourse();
    ArrayList<Mark> marks = appData.getMarks();

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Adapters: "+course.size()+" "+marks.size());
    courseAdapter = new CourseAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.listview_course, R.layout.list_item_mark_name, course);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_course);
    listView.setAdapter(courseAdapter);

    // Setup the grid of Marks to choose from
    marksAdapter = new CourseAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.gridview_course, R.layout.list_item_mark_name, marks);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_course);
    gridView.setAdapter(marksAdapter);
```

And the Layout of that list_item_mark_name :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_mark_name_name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:text="name"
    />
```

I can get them to stack vertically, or even have had them overlay each other in the same space, but no joy side by side.  I have played extensively with weights, relative positioning (toRightOf, etc...) and no go.

I also just tried to give the Grid it's own adapter and created another TextView by a different name for the Grid, to no avail.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the issue.  I removed the line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

From the top of the TextView item I was using to populate the cells of the GridView.  (I did not cut and paste it from my file.  That'll teach me to include EVERYTHING.) Suddenly my grid was visible.  It never caused a problem with my ListView items.

I now can create a prettier group of layouts and got them to align and be visible.

Thanks to anyone who spent time studying this.